# Particle Systems Tutorial/Intro in Three.js

Tags: documentation, three.js, webgl, particle-system

I've been trying to find some good tutorials on particle systems in Three.js, but haven't been able to find anything noteworthy. Is there a particle engine that would be easy to use for it, perhaps with some good intro stuff and documentation? Also, in these particle systems, do I have free reign over positioning of the individual particles, or is it totally random?

Comment: For those visiting in 2020, check out mozilla's awesome tutorial series on particle systems: https://medium.com/@joshmarinacci/threejs-intermediate-skill-tutorials-b48e49e37606 , which are listed (slightly out of order from least to most complicated) here: https://blog.mozvr.com/tag/threejs/

Answer (score 5):

Your best bet is to check out the samples on their [examples page](http://threejs.org/examples/).

In particular:
http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_buffergeometry_custom_attributes_particles

The [three.js documentation page on BufferGeometry](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/BufferGeometry) has docs for all the functions used in those examples, take a look at BufferGeometry and the particle materials.

And yes, you have "free reign", these functions just let you create buffers and render them, you can set the values of the vertices and update them over time however you desire.

Comment: All three links are dead!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! Links updated.